# Count unique values when left join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
1st: Projects >> p_id, p_name, p_description
2nd: Tasks >> t_id, t_project, t_name, t_owner
where p_id is linked with t_prject

The one I´m trying to do is to get the number of projects where one task owner is involved, so I guess I need to join both tables and them makes the filter to get a single number as number of projects someone is involved, looking at other answers I did it like this:

```
SELECT tasks.t_project, COUNT(DISTINCT tasks.t_project ) AS result,
FROM 'tasks' 
LEFT JOIN users ON tasks.t_owner = users.u_id 
WHERE tasks.t_owner=17 
group by 'tasks.t_project'
```

But mysql give an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; on line 3.

Comment: Don't use quotes to escape table or column names. Use backticks

Comment: @sagi: Don't edit away the error in the code

Comment: @juergend Don't edit the code structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quote sign `'` for column/table name, that is wrong and you should have used back ticks . In general, back ticks are used for MySQL reserved words, thats in case you called your table `table` or `max` or any other reserved word. Single quote `'` is used for strings, when putting a text inside quotes it will be automatically recognized as a string.

This query should work:

```
SELECT tasks.t_project, COUNT(DISTINCT tasks.t_project ) AS result,
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.t_owner = u.u_id
WHERE  t.t_owner=17
group by t.t_project
```

Since you didn't use any reserved keywords, I didn't use back ticks, you can also alias the tables names and then you won't have this conflict .

You can [read this documents that provides all of MySQL reserved keywords.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)